# Use effect getting called multiple times

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am using useEffect to change state variables when component mounts. I am using redux for state management. The problem I am facing is that use effect is called multiple times.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    
    dispatch(getSingleCoin(id))

    setName(coinDetail?.name)
    setSymbol(coinDetail?.symbol)
    setLogourl(coinDetail?.logo)
    setPrice(coinDetail?.price)
    setLaunchDate(coinDetail?.launchDate)
    setWebsiteUrl(coinDetail?.websiteUrl)
    setNetwork(coinDetail?.chain)
    setAddress(coinDetail?.address)
    setTwitterUrl(coinDetail?.twitter)
    setTelegramUrl(coinDetail?.telegram)
    setRedditUrl(coinDetail?.reddit)
    setYoutubeUrl(coinDetail?.youtube)
    setCoinDescription(coinDetail?.description)
    setMarketCap(coinDetail?.marketCap)
  }, [coinDetail,dispatch, id, approveSuccess, disapproveSuccess])
```

My useEffect hook that changes state variables.

```
export const coinDetailReducer = (state = { loading: true }, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case COIN_DETAIL_REQUEST:
      return { loading: true }
    case COIN_DETAIL_SUCCESS:
      return { loading: false, coinDetail: action.payload.coin }
    case COIN_DETAIL_FAIL:
      return { loading: false, error: action.payload }
    case COIN_DETAIL_RESET:
      return {}
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

My reducer that handles dispatched action.

Comment: It's most likely because your request sets a new value for `coinDetail` which triggers the hook again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having the action `dispatch` and the handling its response on the same `useEffect` would cause infinite rendering loop. Instead have two different `useEffect`, one to dispatch and other to setState based on the response.

```
useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getSingleCoin(id));
  }, [dispatch, id]);

useEffect(() => {
    setName(coinDetail?.name);
    setSymbol(coinDetail?.symbol);
    setLogourl(coinDetail?.logo);
    setPrice(coinDetail?.price);
    setLaunchDate(coinDetail?.launchDate);
    setWebsiteUrl(coinDetail?.websiteUrl);
    setNetwork(coinDetail?.chain);
    setAddress(coinDetail?.address);
    setTwitterUrl(coinDetail?.twitter);
    setTelegramUrl(coinDetail?.telegram);
    setRedditUrl(coinDetail?.reddit);
    setYoutubeUrl(coinDetail?.youtube);
    setCoinDescription(coinDetail?.description);
    setMarketCap(coinDetail?.marketCap);
  }, [coinDetail]);
```

Comment: This was actually great. Never used more than one useEffect before. I have now grasped the concept pretty well. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The `useEffect` runs every time one of his dependencies changes. So every time one of `[coinDetail,dispatch, id, approveSuccess, disapproveSuccess]` changes, it will run again.

Maybe taking a look on the [useEffect's doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) could help.

Comment: I tried removing the dependencies completely but it still gets called multiple times

Comment: If the dependencies array is empty then the hook will be called once for every `mount` of the component. Maybe your component is mounted multiple times?

Comment: Thanks, coinDetail was the culprit. I removed it from the dependency list and the problem  is gone.

Comment: I'm glad to helped you. Please consider to accept one of the answers as correct in order to help future people to find the solution quickly.